# Best way to convert from scientific notation to decimal?

Tags: python-2.7

I need to convert

```
-5.168070885485833e+19
```

To one contiguous integer, I've tried type casting it to long and that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes - because it's invalid long (int) value. It's valid float value - so `float(s)` given `s` is a string with your representation will convert it to numeric value.

Comment: @Rogalski So I printed the type and it's already a long.

Comment: If it's an integer / long, it's already "one contiguous integer". `str(value)` would return string representation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `print '%li'%(-5.16807088549e+19)`. It will print `-51680708854899998720` which is close.